# Chat application in Rhomobile with asp.net server

Tags: xmpp, chat, rhomobile

I want to integrate a chatapplication in an existing app in Rhomobile (ruby) and my server is a RESTful asp.net mvc server. I didn't find much useful information on how it's done using Rhomobile.

I already did some research and found that many people use xmpp/jabber.
But i don't realy know how to start and how to notify the user when there's a message waiting (if the user is not on the 'chatpage').

I can do polling, but that requires an open connection for every user and i worry about the battery of the mobile device.

Some questions:

1. What to use with a ruby client and an asp.net mvc sever?
2. Should i save the chatdata in the database on the central server since asp.net mvc is stateless?
3. If anyone knows a good guide or tutorial to help me through this, it would be nice - i'm a nembie on this

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what RhoMobile have on their site.

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/connect-to-web-services

I also presume you can use whatever ruby and JavaScript/Jquery code you want.